# How to setup proxy for Chatbot?

Tags: proxy, teams-toolkit

I created a new Chatbot via Teams toolkit according to the tutorial. When I tried to use the 'Debug in Teams' option on the company's intranet which made my pc must use proxy to access the Internet, I received an error message “(×) Error: Unable to execute dev tunnel operation 'create'. Tunnel service returned status code: 407 Proxy Authentication Required”.

As the notification info, I selected 'Debug in Test Tool' option, a web-based Teams chat window launched . I can send messages to the chatbot, but when the bot attempts to reply, it still produces an error.
[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRCxF.png)
When I checked the vscode terminal, error detail is "[onTurnError] unhandled error: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 407".
I think I must setup proxy in this workspace, I tried use "set HTTP_PROXY=xxx" command or add "HTTP_PROXY=xxx" in all the .env files in ./env folder, the error still existed.

Answer (score 0):

For the 'Debug in Test Tool' option, proxy is not needed as it's pure local environment. You can disable the proxy and try it again.

In addition, the http status code 407 means it lacks valid authentication credentials for your proxy server. You may also need to check your proxy if it's requires authentication.

Comment: In fact, I mentioned in my original post that I had already tried that option. Use this option service could launch but the bot only can receive message and meet 407 error neither when it tried to post message to reply. You can check the attach 'log.jpg'